# Vector Projection Problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given vector U with a magnitude of 24 and specified that this vector is at a 60 degree standard position angle. Also given vector V = <5, 2>. What is the vector projection of U onto V?

The instructor calculated the scalar projection using the 60 degree angle, but surely the scalar projection should be calculated using the angle between the two vectors?

This angle would be 60 - arctan(2/5) = 38.2 deg

Then the scalar projection would be 24(cos(38.2)) = 18.9

Then to find the vector projection I would just multiply this by a unit vector in the same direction as vector V. Does this sound correct?

Comment: Yes, you got it.